# How to Convert rdf xml into n-triples?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, xml-namespaces, n-triples

I an RDF document in RDF/XML file that I want to convert into N-Triples.  How can I convert it using Jena?

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/RDFCore/ntriples/">
    <dc:creator>Art Barstow</dc:creator>
    <dc:creator>Dave Beckett</dc:creator>
    <dc:publisher rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file using "RDF/XML" mode and convert it using write function in "N-TURTLE" mode..

ie,

```
m.read(new FileInputStream (new File("yourfile")),"RDF/XML");

m.write(new FileOutputStream (new File("yourfile")) , "N-TRIPLE");
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

According to my reading of [this](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/arp/NTriple.html), you should be able to do it from the command line as follows:

```
    java com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.arp.NTriple filename
```

Comment: Nowadays the "riot" command is better - there are scripts in the bin/ and bat/ directories of the apache-jena download.  They also set the classpath.